# Changing Table name dynamiclly in JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have seen some posts talking about **NamingStrategy** but it is not exacting what I am looking for (or I don't know to to approach it).

I need, depending on some conditions, to change the name of the @Table in the @Entity class passing an ID, something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SA1{companyID}")
public class Cliente implements Serializable, Cloneable {
```

That "companyID" will something like: 010, 020, 030

Is there any whay to achieve that?

Comment: what do you mean "dynamically change" ? You want to change it somewhere and create a new EMF?

Comment: I have these tables **SA1010, SA1030, SA1040** with same structure, depending on what company the user is the selects (this is read only db) are made on different tables, and I would like to use the same entity class.

Comment: yes, and is that one EMF per company? or are you wanting to dynamically select the table mid-EMF ?!

Answer (score 2):

It will be better, if you use `@MappedSuperclass`

```
@MappedSuperclass
class Cliente {

  @Column
  private String xxx;

}

@Entity
class SA1010 extends Cliente { 


}
```

Comment: Thanks, sounds interesting, I will try that

Comment: Yes, this answer solved perfectly my issue here. Thanks a lot my friend.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by implementing **NamingStrategy**

Please see posts below which will help you:

[How do I configure JPA table name at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30987497/how-do-i-configure-jpa-table-name-at-runtime)

[Change Table Name of an Entity on runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879607/change-table-name-of-an-entity-on-runtime)

[Dynamic Naming Table with Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30476844/dynamic-naming-table-with-hibernate)