# Change document name at runtime in Spring Boot Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I am fetching data from api and storing it in database ,I have to delete the whole document and refresh data from api and store it again ,on live server doing this will cause delay for users to get back the data again. Is there any possibility to change the

```
@Document(collection = "events")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
```

collection name at runtime ?? .I have gone through following link -[Changing Table name dynamiclly in JPA/Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37190116/changing-table-name-dynamiclly-in-jpa-hibernate)  for JPA but that doesnt solve my query any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: To paraphrase you want to insert the data you retrieve from the API into different collections based on some conditional using spring-data-mongodb? Is that correct?

Comment: yes and when one collection is deleted suppose i put  a cron job a 3pm everyday so at that time second updated collection will be used

Answer (score 0):

Instead of specifying the collection name in the [Document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/cyrrent/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/mapping/Document.html) annotation I would suggest using [MongoTemplate#insert(Object document, String collectionName)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoOperations.html#insert-T-java.lang.String-) similarly to this [example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#mongo-template.save-update-remove) from the Spring Data MongoDB Documentation.

This way you could specific collection name at runtime using a property or environment variable.